# window 8.1 - how do I restart windows update service

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

Is there an option for this somewhere or is there another way you need to do it? I'm using a surface pro 3 if that makes a difference..

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just type 'Windows Update' in the search.  That'll give you the options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typing the following:

```
net stop wuauserv
net start wuauserv
```

In Command Line will stop and start the Windows Update Service.

There is also a way without command line:

```
Start - Control Panel - Administrative tools - services
```

Look for Windows Update Service. And right-click to stop and start.